# Rails: cannot find '*_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, routes

I'm trying to get a html button to redirect to my Azure login page from the homepage.

If I put in my browser localhost/3000/authentication/login it goes to the Azure web app.

This is what I'm trying to achieve with this:

```
<%= button_to 'Login', authentication_login_path, method: :get %>
```

My routes file is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'application#home'

  get 'application/home'

  get 'authentication/login', to: 'authentication#index'

  resources :authentication

end
```

The Application and Home controllers just have blank functions at the moment.

I've tried rake | grep authentication and it contains the correct path:

```
 authentication_login GET /authentication/login(.:format)                                                          authentication#index
```

Therefore, I'm not sure what doing authentication_login_path is not recognized in my home.html.erg file.

This is the Authentication_Controller. I'm trying to execute the index method as this will begin the authentication process.

```
require 'oauth2'

class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController
  # You need to configure a tenant at Azure Active Directory(AAD) to register web app and web service app
  # You will need two entries for these app at the AAD portal
  # You will put clientid and clientsecret for your web app here
  # ResourceId is the webservice that you registered
  # RedirectUri is registered for your web app
  CLIENT_ID = '56938f79-a23e-4f3f-a033-d23546d9056f'
  CLIENT_SECRET = '5j8Hv8U1x_l-t047OZq9~LmK~kMdobV3rm'
  AUTHORITY = 'https://login.windows.net/'
  AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://beautytruth.b2clogin.com/beautytruth.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_btSignInSignOut/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
  TOKEN_URL = "https://beautytruth.b2clogin.com/beautytruth.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_btSignInSignOut/oauth2/v2.0/token"
  RESOURCE_ID = '/subscriptions/eb589fa5-ed57-4e10-81c9-32e4284af10c/resourceGroups/btAdvertisingNetwork' #ResourceId or ResourceURI that you registered at Azure Active Directory
  REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:3000/welcome/callback'

  def index
    update_token
    if session['access_token']
      puts "Auth has been checked"
      # show main page and use token
      redirect_to
    else
      # start authorization
      client = get_client
      a = client.auth_code.authorize_url(:client_id => CLIENT_ID, :resource => RESOURCE_ID, :redirect_uri => REDIRECT_URI)
      redirect_to(a)
    end
  end

  def callback
    begin
      @code = params[:code]
      client = get_client
      # post token to mobile service api
      #token = client.auth_code.get_token(CGI.escape(@code), :redirect_uri => REDIRECT_URI)
      # id_token token.params["id_token"]
      #multi resource token token.params["resource"]
      token = client.auth_code.get_token(@code, :redirect_uri => REDIRECT_URI, )
      session['access_token'] = token.token
      session['refresh_token'] = token.refresh_token
      session['expire_at'] = token.expire_at
      session['instance_url']  = token.params['instance_url']
      redirect '/'
    rescue => exception
      output = '<html><body><p>'
      output += "Exception: #{exception.message}<br/>"+exception.backtrace.join('<br/>')
      output += '</p></body></html>'
    end
  end

  def update_token
    puts "update token inside"
    token = session['access_token']
    refresh_token = session['refresh_token']
    expire_at = session['expire_at']
    @access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.from_hash(get_client, { :access_token => token, :refresh_token =>  refresh_token, :expire_at => expire_at, :header_format => 'Bearer %s' } )
    if @access_token.expired?
      puts "refresh token"
      @access_token = @access_token.refresh!
      session['access_token'] = @access_token.token
      session['refresh_token'] = @access_token.refresh_token
      session['expire_at'] = @access_token.expire_at
      session['instance_url']  = @access_token.params['instance_url']
    end
  end

  # send post request to webservice to send token and create a post request
  def use_token
    # we got the token and now it will posted to the web service in the header
    # you can specify additional headers as well
    # token is included by default
    update_token
    conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'https://btadvertisingplatform.azurewebsites.net/') do |faraday|
      faraday.request  :url_encoded             # form-encode POST params
      faraday.response :logger                  # log requests to STDOUT
      faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  # make requests with Net::HTTP
    end
    response = conn.get do |req|
      req.url '/api/WorkItem'
      req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
      req.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+@access_token.token
    end
    @out = response.body
  end

  def get_client
    client = OAuth2::Client.new(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, :site => AUTHORITY, :authorize_url =>  AUTHORIZE_URL, :token_url => TOKEN_URL )
    client
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have `resource :authentication` you can use the following.

```
<%= button_to 'Login', authentication_index_path, method: :get %>
```

You don't need an additional route. You can remove the following route

```
get 'authentication/login', to: 'authentication#index'
```